# How to open Windows Explorer by pressing "WIN + E" key using AutoIt

Tags: autoit, windows-explorer

I am able to open Windows Explorer in AutoIt using the following command:

```
Run("explorer.exe")
```

I want to use Win+E key for opening Windows Explorer. What's the command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the funcion [Send](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) with the '#' character to emulate the win+e:

```
Send("#e")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should also work for pressing "Win+e":

```
Send("{LWIN down}{e down}{LWIN up}{e up}")
```